# Why is there a memory leak in this program and how can I solve it, given the constraints (using malloc and free for objects containing std::string)?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, placement-new

This is a minimal working example for the problem I am facing in my real code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace Test1 {
    static const std::string MSG1="Something really big message";
}

struct Person{
    std::string name;
};

int main() {
    auto p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    p = new(p)Person();
    p->name=Test1::MSG1;

    std::cout << "name: "<< p->name << std::endl;

    free(p);

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it and run it via [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind), it gives me this error:

> definitely lost: 31 bytes in 1 blocks

---

### Constraints

1. I am bound to use `malloc` in the example above, as in my real code I use a C library in my C++ project, which uses this `malloc` internally. So I can't get away from `malloc` usage, as I don't do it explicitly anywhere in my code.
2. I need to reassign `std::string name` of `Person` again and again in my code.

Comment: You must call the destructor before `free`.

Comment: When you do a placement-new you must explicitly call the object destructor. Just like `malloc` doesn't construct objects, `free` doesn't destruct objects.

Comment: A case for [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas), if ever I saw one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes thats the problem. Calling destructor before `free` solves the problem. Please write an answer, I will accept it the correct answer.

Comment: *This is Minimal Working Example* -- You forgot `#include <string>` and `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie   It's an understandable oversight though - some (albeit not all) real-world compilers/libraries have `<string>` and `<cstdlib>` are included by `<iostream>` (the standard neither requires nor prevents it).

Comment: The other platform-dependent assumption is writing `malloc` and `free` instead of `std::malloc` and `std::free`.

Comment: I don't see any need for `alignas`, @PaulSanders, given that `std::malloc()` returns memory _suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to
a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement_ (or a null pointer, of course).

Comment: Just so you know, if you get the piece of memory from a C library, and that library passes the memory outside of the process, that std::string will be invalid (unless you have correct serialization routines).

Comment: @TobySpeight OK, let me try again.  I don't like that cast.  I think the code should read: `void *v = malloc(sizeof(Person)); auto p = new(v)Person;`

Comment: Ah, I see what you were getting at, @PaulSanders.  And that does make sense, given that the result of `std::malloc()` is not yet a `Person*`.  It's not clear exactly how the library's allocator is used - if all `Person` objects need to be allocated by the library, that would be a case for defining `Person::operator new()` and `Person::operator delete()` to encapsulate the allocation appropriately.

Comment: As a side-note, given that you specifically say `MSG1` is "really big", and it's a compile-time constant, I'd recommend making it a `std::string_view` (a view of the raw data stored in the executable's constants store) instead of `std::string` (which must be allocated and populated from the constant store at runtime). Just `#include <string_view>`, and if you use `using namespace std::literals;`, initialization simplifies to `static constexpr auto MSG1="Something really big message"sv;` (note `sv` suffix). Not a *huge* difference, but you'll halve memory overhead of `MSG1` and speed startup.

Comment: You say you're bound to using malloc because you're using a C library, but at the same time you are also using a std::string which internally uses the standard C++ `operator new()` instead of malloc. I don't really understand how you end up in a situation where you are required to use malloc while std::string isn't. (This is not a critique, but genuine curiosity.)

Comment: @StackedCrooked I explictly never called `malloc` in my c++ code. I call a C function (from a lib) which internally uses malloc to provide some functionality. This C lib provides its custom freeing method when I wanted to release this memory.  However when I free it that way, it was giving me error. But as other's have pointed out, that if I use `placement new` operator than I do need to call destructor manually before releasing memory. Which on doing so solves the issue.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The important pieces of your code line by line...

Allocate memory for one Person object:

```
auto p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
```

Construct a Person object in that already allocated memory via calling its constructor:

```
p = new(p)Person();
```

Free the memory allocated via malloc:

```
free(p);
```

Calling the constructor via placement `new` creates a `std::string`. That string would be destroyed in the destructor but the destructor is never called. `free` does not call destructors (just like `malloc` does not call a constructor).

`malloc` only allocates the memory. Placement new only constructs the object in already allocated memory. Hence you need to call the destructor before calling `free`. This is the only case I am aware of where it is correct and necessary to explicitly call a destructor:

```
auto p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
p = new(p)Person();
p->~Person();
free(p);
```

Comment: Discussion about comments in code are always a bit tricky, but for me, the only comment in the code I would expect is the reason for using placement-new with malloc (allocator, exercise...)

Comment: It is. And it makes my comment completely moot. Good one.

Comment: To make it _really_ clear what's leaking: because the `Person` destructor isn't being called, `Person::name` isn't being destructed, so the memory allocated by `std::string` isn't being deallocated. That is: `Person` is getting freed, but any memory it points to _isn't_.

Comment: If he didn't have any project constraints, couldn't he just use `delete p;`?

Comment: @AnsonSavage without any constraints they'd probably not use dynamic allocation for something that is basically a `std::string` which already does manage dynamically allocated memory

Comment: @AnsonSavage I think both valgrind and address sanitizer would give an error regarding the mismatch between `malloc` and `operator delete` if you tried to do that.

Comment: To be paranoid, `::new((void*)p)Person()` I think avoids some pathological evil overload issues.

Comment: @AnsonSavage: `new` can adds specific metadata before the allocated item, different (often an expansion of or replacement for) the metadata `malloc` is smuggling. `delete` relies on that metadata to do the cleanup properly. If `new` and `malloc` disagree on the *exact* metadata structure, then `delete` and `free` will as well, and terrible things will happen when you mix them.

Answer (score 35):

You must manually call the destructor before `free(p);`:

```
p->~Person();
```

Or `std::destroy_at(p)`, which is the same thing.

Answer (score 31):

#### Pinpointing the problem

First of all, let us be clear about exactly what the problem is by illustrating the state of the memory after each statement.

```cpp
int main() {
    auto p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));

    //  +---+    +-------+
    //  | p | -> | ~~~~~ |
    //  +---+    +-------+

    p = new(p)Person();

    //  +---+    +-------+
    //  | p | -> | name  |
    //  +---+    +-------+

    p->name=Test1::MSG1;

    //  +---+    +-------+    +---...
    //  | p | -> | name  | -> |Something...
    //  +---+    +-------+    +---...

    free(p);

    //  +---+                 +---...
    //  | p |                 |Something...
    //  +---+                 +---...

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, calling `free(p)` freed up the memory originally allocated by `malloc`, but it didn't free the memory allocated by `p->name` when it was assigned to.

*This* is your leak.

#### Solving the problem

There are two aspects to having a `Person` object on the heap:

- A memory allocation—handled by `malloc`/`free` here.
- *Initializing* and *Finalizing* that memory—handled by calls to constructors and destructors.

You're lacking the call to the destructor, hence resources held by `Person` are leaked. Here it's memory, but if `Person` held a lock you could have a forever locked mutex, etc... executing the destructor is therefore necessary.

The C-style approach is to call the destructor yourself:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto p = (Person*)malloc(sizeof(Person));
    p = new(p) Person();
    p->name = Test1::MSG1;

    std::cout << "name: "<< p->name << "\n";

    //  Problem "fixed".
    p->~Person();

    free(p);

    std::cout << "done" << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

However this is not idiomatic C++: it's error prone, etc...

The C++ approach is to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to ensure that when `p` goes out of scope, all its resources are properly disposed of: the destructor of `Person` is executed *and* the memory allocated for `Person` itself is freed.

First of all, we're going to create some helpers. I used the `c` namespace since I don't know the name of the C library you use, but I invite you to be more specific:

```cpp
namespace c {
struct Disposer<T> {
    void operator()(T* p) {
        p->~T();
        free(p);
    }
};

template <typename T>
using UniquePointer<T> = std::unique_ptr<T, Disposer<T>>;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
UniquePointer<T> make_unique(T* t, Args&&... args) {
    try {
        new (t) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch(...) {
        free(t);
        throw;
    }

    return UniquePointer{t};
}
} // namespace c
```

And with that, we can improve the original example:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto raw = (Person*) malloc(sizeof(Person));

    auto p = c::make_unique(raw);

    p->name = Test1::MSG1;

    std::cout << "name: "<< p->name << "\n";

    //  No need to call the destructor or free ourselves, welcome to RAII.

    std::cout << "done" << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

*Note: Do not use `std::endl`, use `'\n'` or `"\n"` instead. `std::endl` calls `.flush()` on top of putting an end of line, which is rarely what you want -- it slows things down.*

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in other answers, the source of the leak is that the destructor for the `name` member of `Person` does not get called. It would normally be called implicitly when the destructor for `Person` is called. However, `Person` is never destructed. The memory for the `Person` instance is simply released with `free`.

So, just as you had to explicitly invoke the constructor with the placement `new` after `malloc`, you also need to explicitly invoke the destructor before `free`.

You can also consider overloading the `new` and `delete` operators.

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    void * operator new (std::size_t sz) { return std::malloc(sz); }
    void operator delete (void *p) { std::free(p); }
};
```

This way, you can use `new` and `delete` normally, when underneath they will use `malloc` and `free`.

```
int main (void) {
    auto p = new Person;
    //... 
    delete p;
}
```

And this way, you can more naturally use a smart pointer.

```
int main (void) {
    auto p = std:make_unique<Person>();
    //... unique pointer will delete automatically
}
```

Of course, you could have used `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter with your explicit calls to `malloc` and `free`, but it would have been much more cumbersome, and your deleter would still need to know to explicitly invoke the destructor as well.

Comment: Though I might be mistaken, I understand from the question that OP has `malloc`-obtained storage from a C API and must thus use placement-`new` to construct an object in it, i.e., OP is not responsible for the allocation. I don't think overriding `operator new / delete` would make sense in his application if I am correct.

Comment: Note that operator new gets a size as input - so you should normally use that instead of computing sizeof(Person); it is e.g., used by any derived classes (I wouldn't expect any).

Comment: @Erel The minimal example does not illustrate the precise use case, but the example leads us to believe the OP is calling an API to obtain memory for an object, and then is releasing that object. These activities are precisely what overloaded `new` and `delete` can do for you.

Comment: @HansOlsson Fixed. When overloading `new` and `delete`, I usually assume the coder will likely perform the overload for every object, including derived. My code would normally `assert` the provided size matches the size of the `class` that is being allocated.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, dynamic memory allocated by the members of `Person` only gets freed by the destructor `~Person`, which `free()` does not call.

If you have to use this function with a library that requires some initialization and clean-up other than the default, such as here, one approach is to define a new deleter, for the standard libray smart pointers to use:  This will work even with a block of memory you did not allocate yourself.

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <new> // std::bad_alloc
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

struct Person{
    std::string name;
};

struct PersonDeleterForSomeLib {
  constexpr void operator()(Person* ptr) const noexcept {
    ptr->~Person();
    free(ptr);
  }
};


Person* Person_factory() // Dummy for the foreign code.
{
  Person* const p = static_cast<Person*>(malloc(sizeof(Person)));
  if (!p) {
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  }
  new(p) Person();
  return p;
}
```

This lets you safely use:

```cpp
const auto p =
  std::unique_ptr<Person, PersonDeleterForSomeLib>(Person_factory());
```

with automatic memory management.  You can return the smart pointer from the function, and both the destructor and `free()` will be called when its lifetime ends.  You can also create a `std::shared_ptr` this way.  If for some reason you need to destroy the object while the smart pointer is still alive, you can `reset` or `release` it.

Comment: "STL" being some kind of synonym? Not the literal [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I cleaned up the wording on that (and which memory is leaking) slightly.